# TypeError in python while trying to plot a sum

Tags: python, plot, sum

Since I got the advice to make another question here it goes... I want to plot the sum, and I have a code:

```
from scitools.std import *
from math import factorial, cos, e, sqrt
from scipy import *
import numpy as np


def f1(t):
    return 0.5*(1 + sum( (a**(2*n)*cos(2*sqrt(1 + n)*t))/(e**a**2*factorial(n)) for n in range(0,100)))

a=4
t = linspace(0, 35, 1000)
y1 = f1(t)

plot(t, y1)

xlabel(r'$\tau$')
ylabel(r'P($\tau$)')
legend(r'P($\tau$)')
axis([0.0, 35.0, 0.0, 1.0])
grid(True)
show()
```

But I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\faxstuff\3.godina\kvantna\vježbe\qm2\v8\plot.py", line 12, in <module>
    y1 = f1(t)
  File "D:\faxstuff\3.godina\kvantna\vježbe\qm2\v8\plot.py", line 8, in f1
    return 0.5*(1 + sum( (a**(2*n)*cos(2*sqrt(1 + n)*t))/(e**a**2*factorial(n)) for n in range(0,100)))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1415, in sum
    res = _sum_(a)
  File "D:\faxstuff\3.godina\kvantna\vježbe\qm2\v8\plot.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    return 0.5*(1 + sum( (a**(2*n)*cos(2*sqrt(1 + n)*t))/(e**a**2*factorial(n)) for n in range(0,100)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.float64'
```

So what seems to be the problem? It has got to do something with array, but I don't know what :\

EDIT: The picture, in Mathematica looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't divide a `numpy.ndarray` by a `numpy.float64`. This is the problematic code:

```
return 0.5*(1 + sum( (a**(2*n)*cos(2*sqrt(1 + n)*t))/(e**a**2*factorial(n))
```

Comment: But that's the sum I want to plot :\ Why is it so easy to do with Mathematica and so hard with Python? :\

Comment: @dingo_d probably because you're thinking in Mathematica terms and not Numpy terms?

Comment: @ Rafe Kettler: Will you help me learn how to think in Numpy terms? :D

The first part is array, and the second a float. But how to change that?

Comment: @dingo_d unfortunately, I'm a Python guru, not a numpy one. But there are loads of tutorials out there that should get you set.

Comment: isn't numpy a part of python? XD

Comment: @dingo_d it's not in the standard library, so no.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what that generator expression is doing at the end of the return statement in `f1`, but this:

```
a=4
t = linspace(0, 35, 1000)
y1 = numpy.array([f1(t_i) for t_i in t])
```

should get you somewhere. What it does is create a new `numpy.array` by looping through `t`, calling `f1` on each value and building a list from the results. This way the `t` inside `f1` is a single number rather than the whole array at once, which means that your arithmetic can be properly applied to it.

Comment: That should work, in principle, but now he says that there is problem with 'long' and 'float'
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'long' and 'numpy.float64'`

A friend helped me, he solved it by working with discretization - the proper way of doing these things XD

I guess I'm more Mathematica oriented. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Boy, dealing with types in numpy can be weird compared to standard Python! That's the price you pay for speed, I guess. Glad you figured it out.